# how can i check the WordPress is running on local server or is on live server through code

Tags: localhost

I want to check if my site is running on the local server or the live server. I want to run a few methods on the local server and some on the live server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community seems clear enough to me?

Comment: There must be something you can detect about the environment. When you're running on localhost do you set your blog and site URLs to localhost? Else you could pass in an environment variable in one of the environments, or edit the running-on-localhost version of wp-config to have an extra define, etc.